# Cannot set cookie using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, setcookie

I am trying to inject cookies in chrome using selenium execute Script API. I have used the below code to set the cookie -

```html
chrome.cookies.set(cookie, function(state) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(name));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

Cookie Parameter Value - {url:"https://google.com/",name:"Test2",value:"xxxxxx",secure:true,sameSite: "no_restriction",httpOnly:false,expirationDate:1606238940}

I have given cookie permission in manifest.json file.
Above code works fine, for the given url ("https://google.com/").
But when I am trying to inject cookie with url "https://.google.com/", I get the below error in console and cookie does not get injected
**"message: "Failed to parse or set cookie named "Test2"."**

Success Url - "https://google.com/"
Failure Url - "https://.google.com/"
This url format is working for older chrome version, but its failing in newer version. Is there some changes in the latest chrome versions.

Also, I tried inserting the failure url with * ("https://*.google.com") and this got injected.
Is this a valid cookie url ? how is it different from "https://.google.com".

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In modern Chrome you should use the [`domain` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set) instead of dotted urls.

Comment: When i retrieve the cookie using chrome.cookies.getAll() API, i am getting the dotted url. But injection of the same dotted url is failing. Do I need to remove that before injection?

Comment: If my suggestion works then Chrome's behavior may be considered a bug - it shouldn't return a dotted url if it can't set it.